# WinForm Form Launcher (Application.OpenForms)

Tags: c#, winforms

**I call my winforms with the following code:**

```
try
        {
            if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<frmBackupManager>().Count() > 0)
            {
                if (Application.OpenForms["frmBackupManager"].WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                {
                    Application.OpenForms["frmBackupManager"].WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                    Application.OpenForms["frmBackupManager"].BringToFront();
                }
                else
                {
                    Application.OpenForms["frmBackupManager"].BringToFront();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Show Backup Manager                    
                frmBackupManager myBackupManager;
                myBackupManager = new frmBackupManager();
                myBackupManager.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                myBackupManager.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + this.Width / 2 - myBackupManager.Width / 2, this.Location.Y + this.Height / 2 - myBackupManager.Height / 2);
                myBackupManager.Show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBoxEx.Show("Unable to perform requested action: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

**I would like to call this from a method or class but I keep getting an error the type or namespace name 'FormName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
in each place where *FormName* is used.**

```
private void btnBackupManager_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Launch Backup Manager Form
        LaunchForm("frmBackupManager", "MyBackupManager");
    }

    private void LaunchForm(string FormName, string MyForm)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<FormName>().Count() > 0)
            {
                if (Application.OpenForms[FormName].WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                {
                    Application.OpenForms[FormName].WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                    Application.OpenForms[FormName].BringToFront();
                }
                else
                {
                    Application.OpenForms[FormName].BringToFront();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Show Backup Manager                    
                FormName myFormName;
                myFormName = new FormName();
                myFormName.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                myFormName.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + this.Width / 2 - myFormName.Width / 2, this.Location.Y + this.Height / 2 - myFormName.Height / 2);
                myFormName.Show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBoxEx.Show("Unable to perform requested action: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Like other posters have mentioned, you're trying to use the FormName variable as a type.

Try something like this instead:

```
private static void LaunchForm<T>() where T : Form, new()
{
  var existing = Application.OpenForms.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
  if(existing != null) {
    // Make sure existing is visible.
  } else {
    var newForm = new T();
    // Initialize it here.
    newForm.Show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you use a variable as a type. For example, this line:

```
if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<FormName>().Count() > 0)
```

`FormName` may indeed contain the name of the type, but it itself is not a type.

Other lines with this issue include:

```
FormName myFormName;
myFormName = new FormName();
```

You may be able to work around this issue using reflection:

```
if(Application.OpenForms.Where(form => form.GetType().Name == FormName).Count() > 0)
```

```
Form myFormName;
myFormName = (Form)Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().
    GetType("YourNamespace." + FormName).
    GetConstructor(new Type[] {}).
    Invoke(new object[] {});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. How would I "repair" so that the code will work?

Comment: I edited my answer to include a way. (although there's probably a better way that doesn't require hardcoding `"YourNamespace."`)

Comment: This is wrong vision, because FormName is not a local variable, but a type. The error is that local variable name and class names are identical. Easiest way just to rename local variable name to other.

Answer (score 0):

- Your generic function could have an input parameter of type Form (class from which all Win-Forms are derived)
- For Example: -

  private void LaunchForm(Form formToOpen);
- This is so that you could use the object reference where ever required
- And access just the name (the Form class's Name property; Ex: - formToOpen.Name), as applicable and relevant
- This keeps the implementation, strongly typed
- So the required function's implementation could be as follows:

  ```
  private void LaunchForm(Form formToOpen)
  {
      try
      {
          if (formToOpen != null)
          {
              if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().Count() > 0)
              {
                  if (Application.OpenForms[formToOpen.Name].WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                  {
                      Application.OpenForms[formToOpen.Name].WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                      Application.OpenForms[formToOpen.Name].BringToFront();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      Application.OpenForms[formToOpen.Name].BringToFront();
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                  Form formToLaunch;
                  formToLaunch = formToOpen;
                  formToLaunch.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                  formToLaunch.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + this.Width / 2 - formToLaunch.Width / 2, this.Location.Y + this.Height / 2 - formToLaunch.Height / 2);
                  formToLaunch.Show();
              }
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          MessageBoxEx.Show("Unable to perform requested action: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: Tathagat I tried your solution. I still get is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'. I called LaunchForm(frmBackupManager);

Comment: Could you please tell me the exact line of code in the changed function (as per my suggested implementation), at which you are getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you use a type (class name) as a variable.

The error is that local variable name and class name are identical. 
Easiest way to fix the issue, is just to rename local variable name to other.

Here, FormType is a class name, used as a type, but this is wrong usage of class name:

```
if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<FormName>().Count() > 0) 
{
    if (Application.OpenForms[FormName].WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) 
    { 
        Application.OpenForms[FormName].WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal; 
        Application.OpenForms[FormName].BringToFront(); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        Application.OpenForms[FormName].BringToFront(); 
    } 
}
```

Switch to:

```
if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<FormName>().Count() > 0) 
{
    if (Application.OpenForms[childForm].WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) 
    { 
        Application.OpenForms[childForm].WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal; 
        Application.OpenForms[childForm].BringToFront(); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        Application.OpenForms[childForm].BringToFront(); 
    } 
}
```

where *childForm* is a parameter to a method:

```
private void LaunchForm(string childForm, string MyForm)    
{
    ...
}
```